# ReadLinesAsync in array or list

Tags: c#, arrays, list, windows-8.1, readline

I want to read the Lines of a .txt I can read one line with

Code:

```
var Inhalt = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadLinesAsync(Fragendatei);
```

but instead of creating 100 text file i want 1 one text file with 100 lines and select the line i want.

Code:

```
StorageFile Fragendatei = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Fragen/frage1.txt"));
IList<String> inhalt = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadLinesAsync(Fragendatei);
```

My txt have 2 Lines at the moment how can i select the 2 lines would it be a array i could select `inhalt[1]` for example.

Comment: See the documentation of the type that you have for how to get items from it.

Comment: and i don't understand what you mean @Servy

Comment: @ToraAsakura You want to understand how to get the items out of your list.  Look a the documentation for that type and it will tell you how.  You should not be asking us how to do something the documentation explains very clearly.

Comment: @Servy is my code so correct so its possible this way to get the lines?

Comment: @ToraAsakura Try it and find out for yourself if the code that you have will work.

Comment: The `IList<T>` type works just like an array when it comes to indexing specific elements in the collection. Just like in the array scenario ("would it be a array I could select `inhalt[1]` for example"), you can use `inhalt[1]` to index the second line in your `IList<string>` object. It's _exactly_ the same. So, what did you try? What happened? How was that different from what you wanted to happen? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

To be fair, the MSDN documentation for [FileIO.ReadLinesAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh701475.aspx) doesnt provide any sample code as reference.

But since you are getting an IList<> back, this should be quite straightforward. You are on the right track. You got a list, and so, you now need to iterate over the IList<> (using a foreach loop) to get the lines read from the file.

Comment: Could u help me because i don't get it. I can't find how to get the elements out of the Ilist. I would be grateful.

Comment: Really?!
You have `inhalt` which is an `IList<String>`. So, you need to iterate over the list, like this
`foreach (var line in inhalt)
{
  /*do something with each line now*/
}`

Comment: Yes really! I alrdy have the foreach but i dont know what to do in the {} i tried to put it in a array but it dont works i think im do something basically wrong.

Comment: What seems to be the trouble now? Evaluate `row` to "select the line u want."

Comment: That i don't understand the foreach loop. Does it mean that i only can show one line with eacht foreach loop?

Comment: You need to read some documentation then about foreach:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx

Comment: So the row are my lines and for for each element i have in that list it does something, now i tried to do a array with a count      

    int count = 0;
    string[] zeile = new string[5];

    foreach (var row in inhalt)
            {
                count += 1;
                zeile[0] = row;
            }

Comment: Let me ask it this way - what do you want to do next after reading the lines into a list or an array?

Comment: Im try to make a quiz and in the txt, i want to put the question in it. The best way would be i think is to have array (i dont used list so often before just few times in the class) and say     textblock.text = line[1] for example.

Comment: it dont work it say that i need an int the "1" in the indexof("1");
i dont use a foreach at the moment

Comment: hahaha I did it without "" its just for u to know what i mean haha
sorri it says "Argument type 'int' is not assignable to parameter type 'string'"

Comment: Sorry. IndexOf is really about getting to find the index of an item in the list. If you really want to find out the second item in the list, use `inhalt.ToArray()` and then get `zeile[1]`.